# Help required regarding Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I wanted following output from Zend_Form please help

```
<form ...>
<div class="labels"><b>Name:</b></div>
<input type="text" value="" name="name" class="whitelabelform"><br>
<div class="labels"><b>Email:</b></div>
<input type="text" value="" name="email" class="whitelabelform"><br>
<div class="labels"><b>Security code:</b></div>
<div id="recaptcha_cs_fix">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://src"></script></div>
<div id="submitbtn"><input type="image" alt="Submit Button" src="submit_button.png"> 
<input type="hidden" value="true" name="submitted"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: What have you done yet? Have you started creating the form or are you just asking us to code it for you?

Comment: oh! sorry i was away because i didn't got the answer to my question earlier. I coded my form and got a closest one but couldn't get the actual one. i don't know how to add code in it here, as it is to small place for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch this presentation, and you will manage to get any markup of Zend Form you need:

[Leveraging Zend_Form Decorators](http://www.slideshare.net/weierophinney/leveraging-zendform-decorators)

Answer (score 0):

I won`t code it for you but I can point you to a [tutorial](http://akrabat.com/tutorial/simple-zend_form-example/) about Zend_Form. Its very easy to create what you seek take a look at it.

After you have tried if it doesnt work ask again, posting your code and we will help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a form class which your elements are created there and call it in the php (zend view / .phtml file) using something like:

```
<?php echo $this->form->myformelement; ?>
```

provided that your controller also assigns the form created to the variable named "form".